# Python memcache preserve order in get_multi()

Tags: python, memcached, memcachedb

How can I preserve the order of the values fetched with memcache's get_multi() function?  By default, the order returned is random.  Thanks.

Comment: Remember that memcache requests may be hitting many memcache servers, so there's no way you'll actually get the results in any particular order in general.  Any order preservation will be client-side--not preserving order, but restoring it.

Answer (score 3):

Python's Memcache library returns a dictionary, and dictionaries in python are unordered, so you have to get the values from the dictionary in the right order manually:

```
result = cache.get_multi(keys)
values = [result.get(key) for key in keys]
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in the second line, the right side of the assignment should either begin with a bracket or end with a square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

as I remember memcache has flag GET PRESERVE ORDER, try adding this to function flags

Comment: I was able to find this function in php but not in any of the python libraries